# Differential calculus - Error calculation

Tags: calculus, error-function

Let $V_0$ be the volume of a cuboid with the edges $a_0, \ b_0, \ c_0> 0$.

A measurement of the edge lengths yields the values ​​$a, \ b, \ c$ with the absolute errors $\Delta a=a-a_0, \ \Delta b=b-b_0  , \ \Delta c=c-c_0$.

The volume of the cuboid is thus determined with an absolute error $\Delta V = V-V_0$.

How can we explain the following approximation formula for the relative error by means of differential calculus? 
$$\frac{\Delta V}{V_0}\sim \frac{\Delta a}{a_0}+\frac{\Delta b}{b_0}+\frac{\Delta c}{c_0}$$

$$$$

We have that $V(a,b,c)=V(a_0+\Delta a,b_0+\Delta b, c_0+\Delta c)$

Do we use the Taylor expansion? Or is an other meant by "by means of differential calculus" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to use the concept of differential by the gradient, that is

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot h +o(|h|)\implies f(x+h)\approx f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot h\\\implies \Delta f=f(x+h)-f(x) \approx \nabla f(x)\cdot h$$

Indeed in this case we have

- $V=abc\implies \nabla V=(bc,ac,ab)$
- $h=(\Delta a,\Delta b,\Delta c)$

thus

$$\Delta V\approx \nabla V(a_0,b_0,c_0)\cdot h=b_0c_0\Delta a+a_0c_0\Delta b+a_0b_0\Delta c$$

and

$$\frac{\Delta V}{V_0}\approx\frac{\Delta a}{a_0}+\frac{\Delta b}{b_0}+\frac{\Delta c}{c_0}$$

Comment: I understand!! Thank you so much!! At a subquestion: "
Explain how the approximation is to be understood here." do we have to justify that we applied the Taylor expansion? Or how could we explain this?

Comment: That’s a first order approximation which is obtained by the concept of differential. Of course we can also obtain that by first order Taylor’s expansion but it is a more advanced concept and it is not necessary here.

Comment: By "first order approximation which is obtained by the concept of differential" do you mean an aproximation of the derivative?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function

Comment: V is a function of several variables thus we need to refe to the concert of gradient not of derivative.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! :-)